# Livecode httpHeader

Tags: authentication, post, request, http-headers, livecode

Can someone guide me the appropriate way of sending the httpHeaders below. Am getting "Permission Denied" as responds from the server but all looks good with my code.

```
put "ABCD" into clientId
put "1234" into clientSecret

put "Authorization: Basic" && base64Encode("clientId:clientSecret") && "Content-Type: application/json"&& "Cache-Control: no-cache"  into tHeader 
set the httpHeaders to tHeader

 post receiveMomoRequest to url "https://server/v1/merchantaccount/merchants/HMXXXXXX/receive"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each header field should be on a separate line so you should add a return between each key-value:

```
put "ABCD" into clientId
put "1234" into clientSecret

put "Authorization: Basic" && base64Encode("clientId:clientSecret") & return & "Content-Type: application/json" & return & "Cache-Control: no-cache"  into tHeader 
set the httpHeaders to tHeader

post receiveMomoRequest to url    "https://server/v1/merchantaccount/merchants/HMXXXXXX/receive"
```